# No transaction in add_finished_callback() - how can it be restarted?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Using the Pyramid framework and SQLAlchemy as DB backend. I'm trying to defer some long-running HTTP GET requests to a add_finished_callback() on a view, allowing it to render and doing the updates to the database after the view has rendered instead. However, the transaction seems to be closed by the time Pyramid runs the callback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kenne\PycharmProjects\FCMS\venv\lib\site-packages\waitress-1.4.3-py3.8.egg\waitress\channel.py", line 349, in service
    task.service()
  File "C:\Users\kenne\PycharmProjects\FCMS\venv\lib\site-packages\waitress-1.4.3-py3.8.egg\waitress\task.py", line 169, in service
    self.execute()
  File "C:\Users\kenne\PycharmProjects\FCMS\venv\lib\site-packages\waitress-1.4.3-py3.8.egg\waitress\task.py", line 439, in execute
    app_iter = self.channel.server.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\kenne\PycharmProjects\FCMS\venv\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.10.4-py3.8.egg\pyramid\router.py", line 270, in __call__
    response = self.execution_policy(environ, self)
  File "C:\Users\kenne\PycharmProjects\FCMS\venv\lib\site-packages\pyramid_retry-2.1.1-py3.8.egg\pyramid_retry\__init__.py", line 127, in retry_policy
    response = router.invoke_request(request)
  File "C:\Users\kenne\PycharmProjects\FCMS\venv\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.10.4-py3.8.egg\pyramid\router.py", line 260, in invoke_request
    request._process_finished_callbacks()
  File "C:\Users\kenne\PycharmProjects\FCMS\venv\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.10.4-py3.8.egg\pyramid\request.py", line 138, in _process_finished_callbacks
    callback(self)
  File "C:\Users\kenne\PycharmProjects\FCMS\FCMS\views\callback.py", line 25, in test_callback
    print(f"Did some DB stuff, {ct.count()} and {cr.count()}")
  File "C:\Users\kenne\PycharmProjects\FCMS\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-1.3.17-py3.8-win-amd64.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3749, in count
    return self.from_self(col).scalar()
  File "C:\Users\kenne\PycharmProjects\FCMS\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-1.3.17-py3.8-win-amd64.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3469, in scalar
    ret = self.one()
  File "C:\Users\kenne\PycharmProjects\FCMS\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-1.3.17-py3.8-win-amd64.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3436, in one
    ret = self.one_or_none()
  File "C:\Users\kenne\PycharmProjects\FCMS\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-1.3.17-py3.8-win-amd64.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3405, in one_or_none
    ret = list(self)
  File "C:\Users\kenne\PycharmProjects\FCMS\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-1.3.17-py3.8-win-amd64.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3481, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "C:\Users\kenne\PycharmProjects\FCMS\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-1.3.17-py3.8-win-amd64.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3502, in _execute_and_instances
    conn = self._get_bind_args(
  File "C:\Users\kenne\PycharmProjects\FCMS\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-1.3.17-py3.8-win-amd64.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3517, in _get_bind_args
    return fn(
  File "C:\Users\kenne\PycharmProjects\FCMS\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-1.3.17-py3.8-win-amd64.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3496, in _connection_from_session
    conn = self.session.connection(**kw)
  File "C:\Users\kenne\PycharmProjects\FCMS\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-1.3.17-py3.8-win-amd64.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1138, in connection
    return self._connection_for_bind(
  File "C:\Users\kenne\PycharmProjects\FCMS\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-1.3.17-py3.8-win-amd64.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1146, in _connection_for_bind
    return self.transaction._connection_for_bind(
  File "C:\Users\kenne\PycharmProjects\FCMS\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-1.3.17-py3.8-win-amd64.egg\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 458, in _connection_for_bind
    self.session.dispatch.after_begin(self.session, self, conn)
  File "C:\Users\kenne\PycharmProjects\FCMS\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-1.3.17-py3.8-win-amd64.egg\sqlalchemy\event\attr.py", line 322, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\kenne\pycharmprojects\fcms\venv\lib\site-packages\zope.sqlalchemy-1.3-py3.8.egg\zope\sqlalchemy\datamanager.py", line 268, in after_begin
    join_transaction(
  File "c:\users\kenne\pycharmprojects\fcms\venv\lib\site-packages\zope.sqlalchemy-1.3-py3.8.egg\zope\sqlalchemy\datamanager.py", line 233, in join_transaction
    DataManager(
  File "c:\users\kenne\pycharmprojects\fcms\venv\lib\site-packages\zope.sqlalchemy-1.3-py3.8.egg\zope\sqlalchemy\datamanager.py", line 89, in __init__
    transaction_manager.get().join(self)
  File "C:\Users\kenne\PycharmProjects\FCMS\venv\lib\site-packages\transaction-3.0.0-py3.8.egg\transaction\_manager.py", line 91, in get
    raise NoTransaction()
transaction.interfaces.NoTransaction
```

Does anyone know a good way to either restart a transaction in the request-attached ZTM, or should it just be done using a separate db session instantiated in the callback? Or are there reasons not to do db handling at all in the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add_finished_callback` runs after tweens and is generally where cleanup occurs, and is unordered, thus relying on a database connection to be open there is not a good idea.

It's also worth nothing that finished callbacks run in the context of the request, so you are still blocking your response going to the client while they execute, so deferring them until later-in-the-request isn't actually buying you much. You'd have to defer the work to another thread entirely to free up the response to return faster to the client, at which point you'd definitely need to open a new database connection and transaction in that worker thread.

If you're using pyramid_tm with your database, then the connection is closed in the egress of that tween, and accessing objects/database after that will generally be an issue.